# Getting error while installing node packages with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, package

At the end, the package is installed successfully, but I have to retry several times before the installation is done. It doesn't matter what package or if it is global or local.

The messages are as follow:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\david\Dropbox\www\Javascript\nodeuseapi\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\david\Dropbox\www\Javascript\nodeuseapi\node_modules\.grunt-contrib-uglify.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\david\Dropbox\www\Javascript\nodeuseapi\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify' -> 'C:\Users\david\Dropbox\www\Javascript\nodeuseapi\node_modules\.grunt-contrib-uglify.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-09T08_30_20_853Z-debug.log
```

In this case, it was grunt-contrib-uglify, but it could have been any other package.

It also doesn't seem to matter whether if I install from cmd with admin privileges or from VS Code terminal.

I'm under windows 10. Node is v12.18.3. Npm is 6.14.8.

Thank you for any help you can provide on the matter.

Comment: Have you tried to delete `package-lock.json` and then run a fresh `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes I have, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Well, it seems the problem is related to Dropbox as I keep my file in a directory backedup by Dropbox. I've just closed Dropbox and npm seems to be working fine.